# Tree Structure Array full of pointers not structures

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, tree

I need to make a tree structure for the Huffman algorithm. So far, I came up with a way to build up my tree. The problem is that my structure array holds only pointers to objects, not the objects themselves. The code below is a short version of my tree building algorithm. Instead of writing out `abcd`, it writes `cdcd`, since when I create `nd` and `nd2` they become pointers and are saved to the array instead of saving the actual nodes.

I tried to save the nodes to the array without creating new nodes `tmp.Left=&nodes[0]` and it was the same. I need some way to save the nodes directly to the array since I need to merge 2 nodes into a parent and insert the parent into array.

The way I am doing it now is having the parent pointing to 2 fields, where one of them is itself.

I didnt program in ++ for a few years so i am a bit lost whit pointers and stuff.

```
Node* nodes=new Node[1000000];
int numberofnodes=8;

nodes[0].Data='a';
nodes[1].Data='b';
nodes[2].Data='c';
nodes[3].Data='d';

for(int x=0;x<4;x=x+2)
{

    Node tmp;
    tmp.Data=NULL;

    Node nd2=nodes[x];
    Node nd3=nodes[x+1];
    tmp.Left=&nd2;
    tmp.Right=&nd3;
    nodes[x]=tmp;
}

Node tmp3;
tmp3.Data=NULL;
tmp3.Left=&nodes[0];
tmp3.Right=&nodes[2];

printnodes(tmp3);
cout<<endl;
```

short awser :

how to build an tree out of abcd -> ab | cd -> abcd

```
 nodes[0].Data='a';
    nodes[1].Data='b';
    nodes[2].Data='c';
    nodes[3].Data='d';
```

and then puting the parents back into the array

Comment: And your question is? (think of getting onto asking me when meeting in an elevator)

Comment: `my structure array holds only pointers to objects, not the objects themselves.` -- *That's what you want.*  If you need to retrieve the object, then dereference the pointer.

Comment: This code is in serious need of debugging.  You have pointers to temporary values, and the output shows clearly that you are overwriting some locations inadvertently.  You might understand the problems better if you called `printnodes` more often than just at the end, and not just on `tmp3`, especially to see how the trees rooted at `nodes[0]` and `nodes[1]` are modified at each step.

Comment: This `for` loop is hopeless, `nd2` and `nd3` cease to exist at the end of the loop, so your pointers in `nodes[x]` will be wild.

Comment: thats yust a short way of how i build tress. I have a longer way whit more prints and nodes. The problem is if i merge node[0] and node[1] and put the parent into node[0] the parent will point on the node[1] and node[0]->himself instead of the node that used to be 0 and 1